# What can cause the error "Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:]"?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

The full assertion message is:

> Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UICollectionViewData.m:485

What can cause this error?

Answer (score 4):

Not setting the frame of the `UICollectionView` can result in this error.

Comment: Been bitten by that myself.

Comment: Impressive you asked the question and answered it within the same 60 seconds.

Comment: Hah. I do so sometimes to try to help others when I find out the answer to a problem that I wasn't able to find the solution to. There's even an explicit option to answer your own question at the time of posting to make this pattern even easier.